# Controlling an Array of Motors

Tags: arduino, motor, switches, switching

I am trying to measure the state of a switch on a vending machine motor (model # BC-D27/28). It has a micro switch on it that has a lead going from COM1 to NC2 when engaged and COM1 to NO3 when disengaged.

There seems to be a 18 mV state when the switch is engaged that drops to zero when it is disengaged.

The machine is wired only to the + and - terminals of the module.

Ultimately I would like to control an array of these with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

How can I measure the state of the motor's switch to know when to disengage the motor?

[image]

Comment: A micro-switch giving an output between 0 and 18mV seems more like noise which is grounded to me. I think you should check with an Ohm meter what that micro switch does.

Comment: Treat it like any other input switch.  See this [write-up by Nick Gammon](http://gammon.com.au/switches).  (On a different note, I like how the did the cam which pushes the switch.  Simple and cute.)

Comment: the switch terminals are COM, NC and NO ( the digits are just pin numbers)..... that means `common`, `normally closed` and `normally open` ..... in its resting state (nothing is touching the switch) the COM is connected to NC .... when the actuator is pressed then COM is connected to NO ... the COM is not connected to both NO and NC at the same time (except maybe briefly when the actuator is clicked (it  depends on the construction of the switch)  ...... i just noticed that there is a diagram of the switch printed on its case

Comment: @Oldfart Where should I measure to and from?

Comment: @jsotola Thank you for the feedback! I have updated the question.

Comment: Measure all the three? contacts of the switch. On the photo it looks like two? contacts of the switch disappear in the housing. Try to find out where they are going to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch state can be measured with a pullup resistor and a GPIO input.

For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5pVms.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In some cases there may be an internal pullup that you can turn on and even get rid of R1 but it's better to run a bit more current through the switch than internal pullups deliver. R2 provides a bit of protection, and is not strictly necessary. Vdd will be 5V or 3.3V depending on the microcontroller.

If the switch is connected to the motor internally (hard to tell from the photo) you'll likely have to disconnect it or you could damage the microcontroller.

Comment: And if I'm understanding correctly, I could run a wire from the switch output to a microcontroller to measure a V drop?

Comment: You should have the one or two resistors as shown. The GPIO will read '0' with the contacts closed and '1' with them open.

Comment: OK. These are connected in series by row in the machine. Will I need to run a wire from each motor back to the controller?

Comment: For the switches you would need one wire per switch, plus a common ground wire. The resistors should be close to the micro. The  motors would require additional wires, of course.